# Lettuce Redis client doesn't balance load between slave servers

Tags: lettuce

I'm setting up a master/slave Redis topology using the Lettuce client. My readPreference is `slave_preferred` and the topology has three slaves and one master.

The issue I'm experiencing is that once the `StatefulRedisMasterSlaveConnection` is stablished, all queries go to the same slave, instead of balancing the load between all available slaves.

I have also tried adding a `commons-pool2` connection pool as per the documentation, but the behaviour seems to be the same.

I have also tried using a static topology discovery as well as a dynamic one.

Is there a way to balance the load between slaves and not have all queries go to the same slave?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is [no](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/834).

The longer answer is:

> Lettuce selects a replica per slot hash and uses the selected replica for read operations until the next topology refresh. This is by design to reduce CPU overhead.

You might want to follow [ticket #834](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/834) as this one is to add capabilities for load balancing/round-robin across read replicas.